# Apocalypse Now: The end of All. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I am known as the end of all.
When others fall short, I stand tall.
You'll see I can take on different forms,
Don't worry, they are quite the norm.
My brother and I may look a like,
But we are different, as say Paul and Mike.
Sometimes I shoot straight, others I bend,
But do not worry, I don't need to mend.
So answer this riddle if you dare,
The beginning of a laugh is in the air.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer:

> The letter "L"

I am known as the end of all.

> Last letter of "all" is "L"

When others fall short, I stand tall.

> Uncapitalized, the "L" is still big.

Sometimes I shoot straight, others I bend,

> Different types of handwriting, fonts, etc.

The beginning of a laugh is in the air.

> Beginning of "laugh" is "L"

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Good job.  Also, "My brother and I may look alike" - lowercase l looks just like uppercase I.